# DAX: calculating the sum/count for each group

Tags: dax

[image]

Hi, I want to use the DAX to realize the following function shown in Result:

The formula is like SUM(Lead Time） Per “Order Ref"/Count(Order Ref)

Here is an example:

For Ref 1: it should be (3+3+3)/3
For Ref 2: should be (2+2)/2

How can I realize it? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work

```
Evaluate SUMMARIZE(TableName
  , TableName[Order Ref]
  , "Avg Lead Time", AVERAGE(TableName[Lead Time])
  ) ORDER BY TableName[Order Ref]
```

Replace "TableName" with your tablename.

Here's the link to the msdn documentation -

> 1) SUMMARIZE - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492171.aspx
>
> 2) AVERAGE - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634231.aspx

Let me know if that works.